# Data picker icon not shown in ie after file download

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

Data picker icon not shown in IE after file download.

I have used the flowing code in the button event after this the date picker icon disappears.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", "HideProgress
();window.location.href='DownloadFile.ashx';", true);
```

Comment: Could you explain your problem in more detail?

What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have date picker icon in text box. And also having a button click  event in that page. In that event am calling a handler file "DownloadFile.ashx" using ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript after file downloaded using method in handler file my page with date picker is not having calender icon.The reason is the page script execution is stopped during the click event and redirect to the handler file how to rectify this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", "HideProgress();window.open('DownloadFile.ashx','_blank');", true);
```